# Merging DEM files using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, raster, dem, mosaic

I have several DEM files and I want to merge them to create a mosaic.

I found the St_Union(raster) or St_MemUnion(raster) functions but I don't know how to use them.

Are there any other solutions?